# DBIx::Class Error on New and Create

Tags: mysql, perl, dbix-class, dancer

I am using DBIx::Class in a Dancer2 project to talk to a MySQL database.  Within that project, I have a ClassInfo resultset that I can select from, search, delete and update, without problem.

However, whenever I try to add a new row, via:

```
my $new_class = $SCHEMA->resultset( 'ClassInfo' )->new({});
```

or

```
my $new_class = $SCHEMA->resultset( 'ClassInfo' )->create({});
```

(data left out for brevity), I receive the following error:

```
DBIx::Class::Row::has_column_loaded(): Can't call has_column data as class method at /home/jlamey/src/dancer_projects/QP/bin/../lib/QP.pm line 2109

2104      {
2105        flash error => sprintf( 'Class <strong>%s</strong> already exists.' );
2106        redirect '/admin/manage_classes/classes';
2107      }
2108    
2109      my $new_class = $SCHEMA->resultset( 'ClassInfo' )->new(
2110        {
2111          title                => body_parameters->get( 'title' ),
2112          description          => body_parameters->get( 'description' ),
2113          class_group_id       => body_parameters->get( 'class_group_id' ),
2114          class_subgroup_id    => ( body_parameters->get( 'class_subgroup_id' )    ? body_parameters->get( 'class_subgroup_id' )    : undef ),
```

I have even tried submitting both a 'new' and a 'create' command with **zero** data, just to ensure it's not the data that's causing the error, and the error is still thrown.

The table it's trying to write to looks like this:

```
+----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                   | int(8) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| class_group_id       | int(8) unsigned     | NO   | MUL | 1       |                |
| class_subgroup_id    | int(8) unsigned     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| teacher_id           | int(8) unsigned     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| secondary_teacher_id | int(8) unsigned     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| tertiary_teacher_id  | int(8) unsigned     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| title                | varchar(255)        | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| description          | text                | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| num_sessions         | varchar(255)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| fee                  | varchar(100)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| skill_level          | varchar(255)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| is_also_embroidery   | tinyint(1) unsigned | YES  | MUL | 0       |                |
| is_also_club         | tinyint(1) unsigned | YES  | MUL | 0       |                |
| show_club            | tinyint(1) unsigned | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| image_filename       | varchar(255)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| supply_list_filename | varchar(255)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| no_supply_list       | tinyint(1) unsigned | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| always_show          | tinyint(1) unsigned | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| anchor               | varchar(5)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| new                  | tinyint(1) unsigned | YES  |     | 0       |                |
+----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And the resultset looks like:

```
package QP::Schema::Result::ClassInfo;

use base qw/DBIx::Class::Core/;

__PACKAGE__->table( 'classes' );

__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
                          id =>
                          {
                            data_type         => 'integer',
                            size              => 8,
                            is_nullable       => 0,
                            is_auto_increment => 1,
                          },
.
.
.
                          new =>
                          {
                            data_type         => 'boolean',
                            is_nullable       => 0,
                            default_value     => 0,
                          },
                        );

__PACKAGE__->set_primary_key( 'id' );

__PACKAGE__->belongs_to( teacher     => 'QP::Schema::Result::Teacher',       'teacher_id' );
__PACKAGE__->belongs_to( teacher2    => 'QP::Schema::Result::Teacher',       'secondary_teacher_id' );
__PACKAGE__->belongs_to( teacher3    => 'QP::Schema::Result::Teacher',       'tertiary_teacher_id' );
__PACKAGE__->belongs_to( class_group => 'QP::Schema::Result::ClassGroup',    'class_group_id' );
__PACKAGE__->belongs_to( subgroup    => 'QP::Schema::Result::ClassSubgroup', 'class_subgroup_id' );

__PACKAGE__->has_many( dates => 'QP::Schema::Result::ClassDate', 'class_id' );

1;
```

I'm at a loss; no other resultset in this project has this issue, and they're all built the same way.

Thanks in advance for any help.
-- Jason

Comment: The actual problem aside, those three columns for teacher ids are bad design. You should probably normalize your database and use a n-m relationship so you can have an arbitrary number of teachers per class.

Comment: Can you explain more about what you mean? I think I understand in concept, but am not sure I'm clear on it.

There's a 'teachers' table, and those three columns reference that table, since each class listing can have between 0 and 3 listed teachers.

Comment: It's not related to the problem you are seeing, but sure. Your tables are not normalized. You have empty columns for every class entry (row) that only has between 0 and 2 teachers. Only if all three fields are filled in is the space used. That bloats up the database. Furthermore, if you'd have to for some reason add a fourth teacher, you would have to go and change the DDL to add another column, resulting in a write operation on every single row in that table to add a NULL field. That's very inefficient. Instead, you should have a table for classes_teachers that maps that relationship...

Comment: That new tables builds the N:M relation, where each talk can have an arbitrary number of zero or more teachers, and each teacher can teach more than one class. The limit of three per class can be added in the application layer if that's needed. For DBIC, it will be a `has_many` relationship, and you'll have an addition ResultClass. But in total, it's a way more efficient design.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying.  Use a many-to-many relationship mapping, instead.  Yeah, that makes a lot more sense.  And, that is a fairly simple change.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Also, why do you load Dancer2 in the Result class? That will make that object be a Dancer application and is very strange. That might well be the issue here.

Comment: That was a remnant of a desperate attempt to try *anything* I can to solve the above problem.  It isn't permanently in the code.  I should remove it from the example above.

Comment: Did you write the Result classes by hand or are they auto-generated with DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader?

Comment: I wrote them by hand.

Comment: Which DBIC version is this? Maybe there was a bug somewhere that's been fixed. The exception originates in https://metacpan.org/source/RIBASUSHI/DBIx-Class-0.082840/lib/DBIx/Class/Row.pm#L705 btw.

Comment: I would start by eliminating Dancer from the equation completely. Write some command-line tests that try some basic CRUD operations using your classes.

Comment: Also, worth trying with classes that are generated using DBIC::Schema::Loader. I'm not sure why anyone would write those classes by hand.

Comment: @Dave maybe they don't know SQL? ;)

Comment: @simbabque Then they should employ a DBA :-)

Comment: @simbabque: I'm using version 0.082840, which is the latest version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a column named `new` which creates an accessor method named `new` resulting in overriding the classes' constructor method.
This is similar to [DBIx::Class::Manual::Troubleshooting/syntax error at or near "" ...](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/Manual/Troubleshooting.pod#syntax-error-at-or-near-%22%3Csomething%3E%22-...).

Comment: Oh man. I totally overlooked that.  I will make a change and see if that fixes it.

Comment: **THANK YOU!**  This has been driving me batty for days.  You were dead on.